# Minify CSS and JS in Asp.Net when Publish a WebApplication

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, minify, microsoft-ajax-minifier

I use Asp.net 4 C# and MicrosoftAjax Minifier.

Please look at my code here; Using `<Target Name="AfterBuild">` I'm able to minify all files `.js` and `.css`. The problem is that this code minify even the original files in my project solution, so would be almost impossible to edit theme once again.

I need instead minify all `.js` and .`css` on my solution after publishing it to a local folder.

In this way I can keep my original files in my project folder intact and have instead the site compiled and minified into another local folder.

I change my scripting using `<Target Name="Publish">`, I do not receive any error but It does not work.

Could you tell me what I'm missing here, and if there is a better approach to solve this problem? Thanks

```
<!-- Minify all JavaScript files that were embedded as resources -->
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\MicrosoftAjax\ajaxmin.tasks" />
<Target Name="Publish">
    <ItemGroup>
        <JS Include="**\*.js" Exclude="**\*.min.js;Scripts\*.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <CSS Include="**\*.css" Exclude="**\*.min.css" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <AjaxMin
        JsSourceFiles="@(JS)"  JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".js"
        CssSourceFiles="@(CSS)" CssSourceExtensionPattern="\.css$" CssTargetExtension=".css"  />
</Target>
```

Comment: Just a guess, having never used MSAjax to minify, but shouldn't the target filenames include `.min` so you don't overwrite the source files?  eg. `JsTargetExtension=".min.js"` and `CssTargetExtension=".min.css"` ?

Comment: VS do not let me publish the file with extension .min.js, for this reason I wrote this question.

Comment: at the moment I'm using also a version with -min.css and -min.js, this allowed be to have file automatically published, but I think it is not a clean solution plus I have to change the path for my resources.

Comment: This article on the MS Ajax site shows how to do this: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxminquickstart.ashx

Comment: Thanks Will, the script in the tutorial does the trick, but as I sad I have problem to include the .min.js file when using the PUBLISH features in VS. DO you know a way to include this file when publishing my web application?

Comment: Does this article help? (sorry, it's big) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043504/using-microsoft-ajax-minifier-with-visual-studio-2010-1-click-publish

Comment: thanks to point me out this article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(copied from questions)

To deal with losing the original js/css files, ensure the target filenames include .min, eg. `JsTargetExtension=".min.js"` and `CssTargetExtension=".min.css"`.  See article on using MsAjax minifier: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxminquickstart.ashx

To then be able to publish the minified files, see this article: [Using Microsoft AJAX Minifier with Visual Studio 2010 1-click publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043504/using-microsoft-ajax-minifier-with-visual-studio-2010-1-click-publish)

At my workplace, we are solving the minifying issue quite differently by using Chirpy addin for Visual Studio.  It automatically minifies files to a .min version upon saving.  See http://chirpy.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks wil for your answer, interesting app chirpy I will have a look for sure.